# fix grammar issues

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am trying to make a notification in my android application, I received my data from my server Spring Boot when I get some numbers I want to notify my app so here is my code:

```
public class InformationNow extends AppCompatActivity implements 
   SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
        private  InformationNowAdapter informationNowAdapter ;
        private String url = "http://192.168.1.90:9090/TrashCanData/lastrow";
    
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_information_now);
    
    
            refresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.Swiper);
            recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.Now);
    
            dialog = new Dialog(this);
    
         Timer repeatTask = new Timer();
            repeatTask.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        trashCanModels.clear();
                        getData();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
    
    
        }
    
        private void getData() throws InterruptedException  {
            refresh.setRefreshing(false);
    
            arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    
    
                    try {
                            //JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            final TrashCanModel  cat = new TrashCanModel();
                            cat.setDistance(jsonObject.getInt("distance"));
                            cat.setTemperature(jsonObject.getInt("temperature"));
                            cat.setHumidity(jsonObject.getInt("humidity"));
                            Log.e("*********", cat.getDistance().toString());
                            Log.e("*********", cat.getTemperature().toString());
                            Log.e("*********", cat.getHumidity().toString());
    
                            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    try{
                                        if(cat.getDistance()<8 || cat.getHumidity()>90 || cat.getTemperature()>27){
    
                                        notifications();
    
                                    }
                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        Log.e("EXCEPTION", "Inside thread: " + e.getMessage());
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                            t.start();
    
    
    
                            trashCanModels.add(cat);
    
    
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
    
                        }
    
                    adapterPush(trashCanModels);
                    refresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    
                }
            });
    
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(InformationNow.this);
            requestQueue.add(arrayRequest);
    
            //Thread.sleep(9000);
    
        }
    
        private void notifications() {
    
             NotificationCompat.Builder notification_builder;
            NotificationManager notification_manager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                String chanel_id = "3000";
                CharSequence name = "Channel Name";
                String description = "Chanel Description";
                int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW;
                NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(chanel_id, name, importance);
                mChannel.setDescription(description);
                mChannel.enableLights(true);
                mChannel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
                notification_manager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
                notification_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, chanel_id);
            } else {
                notification_builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
            }
            notification_builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo1)
                    .setContentTitle("Notification Title")
                    .setContentText("Notification Body")
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
        }
    
        private void adapterPush(ArrayList<TrashCanModel> trashCanModels) {
    
            informationNowAdapter = new InformationNowAdapter(this, trashCanModels);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(informationNowAdapter);
    
    
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            trashCanModels.clear();
            try {
                getData();
                //Thread.sleep(4000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
    }
```

but I don't get any notifications, the function called `notifications()` in my condition but I didn't receive anything from a lot of phones: android 9, and 7 and 8...
So can you help me to make it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your `notifications` function, you need to add something like:

```
// notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
notification_manager.notify(notificationId, notification_builder.build());
```

cf the documentation: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification

Comment: didn't work after add `notification_manager.notify(1, notification_builder.build());` inside if and else